# How can I insert this entry into my dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a swift class called ArticleArchive as follows

```
import Foundation

class ArticleArchive: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var entries: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>?

    var userDefaultsKey = "savedArticles"

    override init() {
        self.entries = Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>()
    }

    init(articles: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>) {
        self.entries = articles
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.entries = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(userDefaultsKey) as? Dictionary
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let articles = self.entries {
            aCoder.encodeObject(articles, forKey: userDefaultsKey)
        }
    }

    func populateArticles(articles: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>) {
        self.entries = articles
    }

    func save() {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: userDefaultsKey)
    }

    func clear() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(userDefaultsKey)
    }

    class func loadSaved() -> ArticleArchive? {
        if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedArticles") as? NSData {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? ArticleArchive
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

In a viewController, I have the following var of type `ArticleArchive` at the top of the class

```
var savedArticles : ArticleArchive? = nil
```

In `viewDidLoad` I do the following to initialise the variable

```
    if let savedArticles:ArticleArchive = ArticleArchive.loadSaved() {
        self.savedArticles = savedArticles
    } else {
        self.savedArticles = ArticleArchive()
    }
```

I am trying to insert a `Dictionary<String, String>` into the `savedArticles` variable like so but it doesn't work.

```
let currentDictionary = filtered[indexPath.row] as Dictionary<String, String>
self.savedArticles?.entries[currentDictionary["link"]] = currentDictionary
```

I get an error that states "Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments"

I've gone around in circles trying different things but no luck, maybe someone can help me out.  How can I insert currentDictionary (a `Dictionary<String, String>`) into `savedArticles`?

Comment: Mmh, basically it seems to be telling you that whatever is inside the brackets of `entries[ ]` is of the wrong type. Since `entries` is a `Dictionary` with keys of type `String`, it should resolve to a `String`. Did you try casting? (use `as`/`as!`/`as?`)

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of, I just updated the question because it didn't reflect the last thing I tried

Comment: Does `currentDictionary["link"]` resolve into a `String`? You can use an intermediate variable, for example `let key:String = currentDictionary["link"]; self.savedArticles?.entries[key] = currentDictionary`. Where does the error caron (`^` cursor) point in the source code editor?

Comment: Yes it resolves to a `String`.  I also tried with an intermediate variable cast to `String`.  The `^` cursor points at the `=` symbol in the updated example `self.savedArticles?.entries[currentDictionary["link"]] = currentDictionary`

Comment: If the `^` points to the assignment operator (`=`), then it means that not the dictionary key (String) but the type of **the value** (`currentDictionary`) is incompatible with the subscript. So, you are trying to insert a dictionary of the wrong signature?

Comment: Oh, look... both answers suggest that you unwrap `currentDictionary["link"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The insertion works, if the dictionary `entries` is non-optional**

There is a good reason to use non-optional types.

Let's assume that when the object `ArticleArchive` exists, there exists also the `entries` dictionary which is empty by default.

The `encodeWithCoder` and `init(coder)` methods are also safe, because it's ensured that the non-optional `entries` dictionary is saved anyway even if it's empty, so it's never nil.

Here's the code

**Edit** : I added a type alias `ArticleDictionary` for better readability

```
class ArticleArchive: NSObject, NSCoding {

  typealias ArticleDictionary = Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>

  var entries: ArticleDictionary

  var userDefaultsKey = "savedArticles"

  override init() {
    self.entries = ArticleDictionary()
  }

  init(articles: ArticleDictionary) {
    self.entries = articles
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.entries = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(userDefaultsKey) as! ArticleDictionary
  }

  func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
      aCoder.encodeObject(self.entries, forKey: userDefaultsKey)
  }

  func populateArticles(articles: ArticleDictionary) {
    self.entries = articles
  }

  func save() {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: userDefaultsKey)
  }

  func clear() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(userDefaultsKey)
  }

  class func loadSaved() -> ArticleArchive? {
    if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedArticles") as? NSData {
      return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? ArticleArchive
    }
    return nil
  }

}
```

as the `link` key might not exist, the value must be unwrapped.

```
savedArticles.entries[currentDictionary["link"]!] = currentDictionary
```

Comment: You say that "The insertion works, if the dictionary `entries` is non-optional". So, alternatively he could just force-unwrap `entries` prior to insertion? (risking a runtime crash, of course)

Comment: That's what my answer does and yeah it risks a runtime crash.

Comment: that's why I recommend to use a non-optional type. It worth it to wonder about non-optional types at compile time to be safe at runtime

Answer (score 1):

I modified your class to have this method:

```
func addEntry(key:String, dict:Dictionary<String,String>){
    self.entries![key] = dict;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
 self.savedArticles?.addEntry(currentDictionary["link"]!, dict: currentDictionary)
```

Seems to work.

EDIT : If for some reason `entries` has to remain optional, then this can prevent a runtime crash (bit hacky but works)

```
func addEntry(key:String, dict:Dictionary<String,String>){
    if let e = self.entries{
        self.entries![key] = dict;
    }else{
        print("avoided runtime crash!")
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked but I think the other answer is a better solution in my case